# Default Java not detected by Maven as installed

Tags: java, jdk, default-programs, jre, maven-3

I have an Ubuntu installation with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_141 that was installed using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps).

`tar` file was extracted to `/opt/jdk` and below commands used to set `java` as default.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
```

`java -version` command works fine after these have been completed, but when I try to install `maven` using `apt-get` it tries to install `default-jre` rather than using this installed version.

Do you have any idea how I can change this default behavior?

Comment: The problem is that apt cares about packages, not programs. The formerly recommended way to install Oracle Java was from the [webupd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) however I'm not sure if that advice is still current. Otherwise, you could consider using `make-jpkg` as described here [davmail and JAVA INSTALLED MANUALLY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129475/65304) (I've never tried this personally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved after setting the kava alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javaws" 1
```

It still install the default jdk when installing maven. But uses oracle jdk when building.

Thanks for the wikihow page : https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux